# intercept form submit response

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to intercept my form's submit response via javascript. Submit is normally done by a submit button or jquery's `.submit()` (with no params). Is there a way to intercept that submit **response** like;

```
.submit().done(callback)
```

I know `.submit()` does not have support for this, however creating a post request like finding every input in that form and getting their values into data object which we will then pass to `.post()` method seems a bit clumsy to me. Besides there will be no advantage of using `<form>` tags in html in that approach.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: use the 'clumsy' method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

Besides, when you do `.submit()` or click submit button, the page unloads and a new page loads. which means all java script on the page is gone so there is no point in having a callback.

Comment: In fact `.serialize()` can be useful in this situation.